# Copying of folder in inno script

Tags: inno-setup

I have a folder called webcam-applet, I want to copy the whole file into local\Temp on running the .exe file. I have created the inno script file to copy the contents of web-cam applet but, I need the folder there for my application to work. Please tell me if there is away to do this . My statement is given below.

```
Source: "WebcamApplet_1-0-0\*"; DestDir: "{%TEMP}"
```

This will copy the contents. If I remove the "*" and "\" an error is generated.

Comment: Your `[Files]` entry now copies the whole content of a folder called `WebcamApplet_1-0-0` which is a subfolder of a folder, where your script is saved to the folder specified by the `%TEMP%` environmental variable on the target machine. I can't see anything wrong on this. You probably want to change something on that, but it's hard to say what. Do you want to modify that entry so the target will be different, maybe the folder which the user choose as a target of the installation ? Or something else ? Could you edit your question and elaborate this, please ?

Comment: My question is, if there is a way to copy the WebcamApplet_1-0-0 folder with its contents to the location.

Comment: But which location ? The folder which the user choose as a target of the installation on the *Select Destination Location* wizard page ?

Comment: This location to be exact. C:\Users\Manesh\AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313269/how-to-copy-files-into-appdata-local-temp-in-inno-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the path you've specified in your comment doesn't belong to [`known folders`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and so there is no constant for it in InnoSetup, you'll need to expand the parent [`{localappdata}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=localappdata) folder constant adding the `Temp` location to it. In script it would be:

```
[Files]
Source: "WebcamApplet_1-0-0\*"; DestDir: "{localappdata}\Temp"
```

Comment: How it didn't work ? This will set as a destination directory path specified by the [`CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494(v=vs.85).aspx#CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA) and append a `Temp` to the end.

Comment: I got this, it is working correctly, but it is not getting copied to user accounts temp folder, it is only going inside the admin's temp folder.