# How to copy files into AppData\Local\Temp in inno script

Tags: inno-setup

I have created an .exe file for my application using inno script. Here I want to copy files from my setup folder to the AppData\Local\Temp directory. This is done using the below code.

```
Source: "WebcamApplet_1-0-0\*"; DestDir: "{localappdata}\Temp\WebcamApplet_1-0-0"
```

The problem I'm facing is that this code is only copying the files into the sysadmin ie C:\Users\Sysadmin\AppData\Local\Temp (Admin), I have to put it in C:\Users\Manesh\AppData\Local\Temp(User) for my application to work. How do I solve this problem.

Comment: If you want to copy files into users Temp folder you can use `{%TEMP}` constant. Keep in mind that user can set Temp folder to different location. By using this constant you will always get the correct path for users Temp.

Comment: {tmp} will access only C:\Windows\Temp not C:\Users\Manesh\AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: `{tmp}` is Inno Setup's "private" temp (e.g. "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\IS-xxxxx.tmp"). See doc: [Inno Setup Consnstants](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts)

Comment: i checked the documentation and tried it, it does not copy into the location that is said above.

Comment: if you mean `{tmp}` and `C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\IS-xxxxx.tmp` then this is just an example, not the real location. It just shows, that Inno Setup creates it's own folder on each setup run. Try to call `ECHO %TEMP%` in Command Line to check if you will get the Temp folder you look for. If yes, then `{%TEMP}` will be you constant for the script.

Comment: I got the same temp folder in command prompt but it is not working inside the inno script  
    Source: "WebcamApplet_1-0-0\*"; DestDir: "{%TEMP}"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35757/discussion-between-user2655318-and-roben)

Comment: `Source: "WebcamApplet_1-0-0\*"; DestDir: "{%TEMP}\WebcamApplet_1-0-0"; Flags: createallsubdirs recursesubdirs` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your application is badly designed if it expects files to be installed to the Temp folder.  This folder is so named because the user or the system are free to delete all files contained therein at any time -- it is therefore suitable only for temporary use.

Additionally, there is no reasonable and reliable way for a per-machine installer (one running with `PrivilegesRequired=admin`, which is the default) to install files or settings to per-user folders, including the per-user temporary folder.

If you really really want to do this, you should set `PrivilegesRequired=lowest` to create a per-user installer -- but bear in mind that this will introduce other restrictions, such as limiting where your application can be installed to.  Provided that you are running with lowest privileges, you can then use `{%TEMP}` to refer to the temporary path.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, don't you know if there's a way to get the logged on user's token from an impersonated process (for the `hToken` parameter of the `SHGetFolderPath` like functions) ? That would be the way to get the desired path (and the exact answer to this question; not *correct*, but exact).

Comment: You can get the desktop window, and the owning process of that window, and then the token that the process is running with.  But it's unnecessary in "lowest" installers (as the installer will already be running with the correct user) and it's a bad idea in "admin" installers (as it means that the installation step is being done in the wrong place, so the application will only work for a subset of users).  For a per-machine installed app, any per-user setup should be done by running the application itself, not the installer.